# empty useState on request React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am using a button to perform a fetch request, when I do it and try to set the response in useState it always stays empty but if I click the button again now it sends me the information correctly.

This is my code:

```
  const fetchUsers = async (page, limit = perPage, search = searchBox, type) => {

    if (type === 'all') {
      limit = 100000
    } else {
      setLoading(true);
    }

    const dataOnLs = localStorage.getItem('cmtjs')

    const config = {
      headers: {
          "Content-Type": "application/json",
          apiKey: dataOnLs
      } ,
      params: {
          limit,
          page, 
          search
        }            
  }
    const response = await axiosClient(`/products`, config)
    console.log(response.data.products.docs); // DATA OK
    if (type === 'all') {
      setDataToXLS(response.data.products.docs); // **EMPTY**
    } else {
      setData(response.data.products.docs); // DATA OK
      setTotalRows(response.data.products.totalDocs);
      setLoading(false);
    }
  };
```

I don't understand why it doesn't set my useState (setDataToXLS) with the data on the first click and I have to click twice to get the data correctly

Comment: What is `type` doing through the cycle? Log `type` right before your conditional to see what the state is at each point.

Comment: Please post the rest of the variables, e.g. how you're triggering this, what variables are being passed to the fetch function, how you're rendering the output.  Have you made sure that type==='all' conditional is actually being met? It would make no sense that it's "ok" one line before, and the same data is different in the next line.  There must be another problem. Hard to say without knowing how you're rendering it for example.